# Tab shortcut doesn't add the slash to the end of the suggested directory name

Tags: powershell, command-prompt

I would expect the suggested name ends with a '\' if it's a directory, so I can continue to type in the first letters of the next name down the path, and use tab again.
I don't know when it started, but on one of my PCs, Powershell just won't add the slash.
It's been painful to type all the extra '\'s. Does anyone know if there's a setting?

---

I got my Powershell back to normal after I followed the instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57032747/how-to-change-powershell-mode-to-fulllanguage-mode-from-constrained-mode) to get it working with core method calls.

Running the following command doesn't bring back the "bug" like before.

> $ExecutionContext.SessionState.LanguageMode = "ConstrainedLanguage"

But setting that __PSLockdownPolicy registry key back to 4 does.

Comment: Not sure about the autocomplete, but Join-Path can save you worrying about slashes in powershell.

Comment: Ditto, or use System.IO.Path [Combine()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.combine)

Comment: OK, but the point is to fix autocompletion so I can follow down a path without pressing '\' at every level.

Comment: Did you perhaps remove `PSReadLine` by accident? Do you have `Remove-Module PSReadLine -Force` or similar in your profile?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen No, I ran "Module", and it was listed, v 2.0.0.